# Asp.Net Core Package Manager Console. Installing NuGet library not creating a library/script folder

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

I've seen other solutions when installing a NuGet package, in a web project, a folder is created to simply drag a script tag into a HTML document. This is done in Visual Studio of course. I've installed jQuery and jQuery-Validation to my NETCoreApp and am quite confused on how to enable the folder creation to drag these references into my page.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net Core, Nuget is used for server side packages & Bower for client side packages.

To get the folder for scripts, do the following:

1. Add 'Bower Configuration File' to the project.
   [image]
2. Under 'dependencies', add all the dependencies needed. For example:
   [image]
3. Save the file. You should see all the scripts being restored.
4. There should be a lib folder created under wwwroot. You should see all the dependent scripts under lib from which you can drag the references to your pages.

Comment: Doesn't work on Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core 2.0 on Mac